# How to insert Dropdown Pages in Separator of wp_link_pages() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Respectable Gurus
I want to add dropdown page numbers in place of separator in wp_link_pages() array
bellow is my code which throughs syntax error, unexpected token "for" in
Please help to resolve my issue

```
<?php
global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;

wp_link_pages( array(
'before' => '<div class="pagination">',
'after'=> ' </div>',
'link_before'=> '<span class="page-link">',
'link_after'=> '</span>',
'navwidth'=> 3,
'next_or_number'=> 'mixed',
//'separator'=> ''. __( 'Page ' ) . $page . __( ' of  ' ) . $numpages . __( ' pages' ) .'',
'separator'=> ''. __( '<select onchange="javascript:gotoPage()" id="page">' ) . for($x = 1 $x <= $numpages $x++) { . __( '<option value="' ) . echo $x; if($x==$page) echo "selected" . __( '>'     ). echo $x . __( '</option>' ).} __( '</select>' ) .'',
'nextpagelink'=> __( 'Next' ) . ' >',
'previouspagelink' => '< ' . __( 'Previous' ),
) );
?>
```